# Use ajax with flask to update a table

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have a page on my site with two contents that needs around 10sec to be calculated. I don't want to let users wait for so long until the page loaded. I thought to load the page without the content and then use ajax to send a request onwindow load to calculate those contents and then add them to the content. Until then a loading circle is perfect. The problem is that I haven't used ajax before and I feel lost. 
**EDIT 1:**

I try to experiment with jquery and ajax. I did a few things but I have an error.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="image" class="span3">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function jqueryonload() {
        $.getJSON('/_jqueryonload',{

        "links": {{links}} #links is a jinja variable I pass on render and I want to use it again
        }, 

        function(data) {

          $("#image").html(data.image);

        });
        return false;
        });

        window.onload = jqueryonload;
 </script>
```

**And here is the flask code:**

```
@app.route('/_jqueryonload')
def jqueryonload():

    links = request.args.get('links')
    image_v = image_def(links) # this is a function that find the link of the image

    image = '''<img src="%s"/>''' % (image_v)

    return jsonify(image=image)
```

I don't know what the problem is, but the image doesn't show at all :(

Answer (score 0):

You clearly are not passing the task object to the template, that's why you can't use it. I haven't used flask but you might get away passing `task` and `links` as a dict.

```
return render_template("task_details.html", {'links': links, 'task': task))
```

This is an example using bottlepy and ajax, is quite similar to flask

ajax call:

```
$.ajax(url: '/methods/12',
type: json, 
data: somedata,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
});
```

python:

```
@route('/methods/<id>', method='GET')
def getUserStatus(id='0'):
    # Get user status info
    try:

        con = pymysql.connect(user=dbUser, passwd=password, host=dbHost, port = dbPort, db=database)
        cursor = con.cursor()
        status = cursor.execute("SELECT account_number,account_type FROM payment_methods")
        status = cursor.fetchall()
        con.close()
    # handle mysql errors   
    except pymysql.Error as error2:
        message = ({"result":"error","error_name":error2[1]})
        return json.dumps(message)
    # Preparing response
    q = len(status)
    columns = zip(*status)
    acc_n  =columns[0]
    acc_t = columns[1]
    #acc_n = [x for (x,y) in status]
    #acc_t = [y for (x,y) in status]
    message = ({"result":"OK","q":q,"acc":acc_n,"name":acc_t})
    # Return
    return json.dumps(message)
```

Comment: I remove it from there because I want to request it from ajax request. It was intentional

Comment: using ajax in python is quite simple, use javascript or jquery to make the call, in 'url' place the url from here @app.route("/task/<title>"), i.e. url: '/task/sometitle' and that function should return a json object, like return json.dumps(data)